# jQuery apend a div to an existing element including that element inside apended div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this scenario :

```
<div class="paper jpaper  form-group">
        <label class="control-label">User comments</label>
```

> ```
> <!-- here must be inserted append -->
> ```

```
        <textarea placeholder="Enter text" class="form-control input-sm"></textarea>
```

> ```
> <!-- and here must close the appended div and will include textarea -->
> ```

```
</div>
```

So how can I append a div that will include the existing textarea, but I don't want to remove the existing `<textarea>` and add again because that `<textarea>` si created dinamyc and has some clases and id's dinamically added.

Comment: adding an `$(".paper").append("<textarea class='' id=''></textarea>");` with jQuery would do it, isn't it? it will append that textarea at the end of the element ".paper"

Comment: @Cheshire I want that existing <textarea> to be included inside appended div, not to append that textarea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this using jQuery:

```
$('.paper > textarea').wrap('<div class="wrapper">');
```

This code simply wraps your textarea.

Or even without jQuery:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.paper textarea');
el.outerHTML = '<div class="wrapper">' + el.outerHTML + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(".paper textarea").wrap("<div></div>");`

It'll produce the following:

```
<div class="paper jpaper  form-group">
    <label class="control-label">User comments</label>
    <div>
        <textarea placeholder="Enter text" class="form-control input-sm"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

See http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(".form-group>.form-control").appendTo(
    $("<div class='test'/>").appendTo(".jpaper")
)
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hjj131y1/)